# Qt5 C++ connect triggered QAction to a member function

Tags: c++, qt5

Why can't I connect the action to call the function if triggered?
I thought that I've understood the syntax according to this [source](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)
that states one can call a function directly.

```
void Traymenu::createMainContextMenu(){
    QAction *actionNewNote = mainContextMenu.addAction("Test Func");

    QObject::connect(actionNewNote,QAction::triggered,Traymenu::testFunc);

    mainIcon.setContextMenu(&mainContextMenu);

}

void Traymenu::testFunc(){
    printf("test func");
}
```

Error:`invalid use of non-static member function 'void QAction::triggered(bool)`

```
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass pointers to functions into `connect`.  You also need to pass in a pointer to the receiving object:

```
QObject::connect(actionNewNote, &QAction::triggered, this, &Traymenu::testFunc);
```

Note the "`&`" prior to `QAction::triggered`.

Comment: Okay I will give it a try. To teh receiving Object: did you read the link? You can also  name a function directly without "this" as I understand it

Comment: Yes, you can name a function directly.  BUT, if the function is a member function, you must either use `tr1::bind`, or pass in a pointer to the receiver as I've done above.  It is not sufficient to just pass in a pointer to the member function.